# image overlapping issue in desktop for bootstrap foundation theme

Tags: image, zurb-foundation, overlap

http://techjour.in/master/top-artists.php

Image Overlaps on other images on Page loading on server but locally no problem.

Comment: is anyone, who can solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your class, for your 4th grid should be position: absolute; left: 0; top: 427px;

Comment: but these css generates with jquery

Comment: see that link, same overlapping problem, it will seem after ctrl f5

Comment: Ok i see what the issue has to do with collapsing parents and clearfix, check out this link here to see how they solved the problem you are having: http://designshack.net/articles/css/everything-you-never-knew-about-css-floats/ and also this video http://css-snippets.com/collapsing/